# My JavaScript countdown is counting down to the wrong date after I added years

Tags: javascript, html, date, timer, countdown

## My JavaScript countdown is counting down to the wrong date after I added years.

I am trying to create a html document that counts down to a specific date (July 4th 2026), but the numbers are off by a few dozen days. What am I doing wrong?

Most of it is copied from a template I found online ([this one](https://codingartistweb.com/2021/12/new-year-countdown-html-css-javascript/)), but I added another box to include the year and added some more variables and calculations to populate the yearBox.

Here's the code:

```js
let yearBox = document.getElementById("year-box"); // this part I added to make the year box
let dayBox = document.getElementById("day-box");
let hrBox = document.getElementById("hr-box");
let minBox = document.getElementById("min-box");
let secBox = document.getElementById("sec-box");
let endDate = new Date(2026, 07, 04, 00, 00); // I changed the date from the template
let endTime = endDate.getTime();

function countdown() {
  let todayDate = new Date();
  let todayTime = todayDate.getTime();
  let remainingTime = endTime - todayTime;
  let oneMin = 60 * 1000;
  let oneHr = 60 * oneMin;
  let oneDay = 24 * oneHr;
  let oneYear = 365 * oneDay; // I added this calculation to help the year calculations

  let addZeroes = (num) => (num < 10 ? `0${num}` : num);

  if (endTime < todayTime) {
    clearInterval(i);
    document.querySelector(
      ".countdown"
    ).innerHTML = `<h1>Event has passed</h1>`;
  } else {
    let yearsLeft = Math.floor(remainingTime / oneYear); // the original template had the largest box in days, but I changed it to create a "yearsLeft" variable.
    let daysLeft = Math.floor((remainingTime % oneYear) / oneDay);
    let hrsLeft = Math.floor((remainingTime % oneDay) / oneHr);
    let minsLeft = Math.floor((remainingTime % oneHr) / oneMin);
    let secsLeft = Math.floor((remainingTime % oneMin) / 1000);

    yearBox.textContent = addZeroes(yearsLeft);
    dayBox.textContent = addZeroes(daysLeft);
    hrBox.textContent = addZeroes(hrsLeft);
    minBox.textContent = addZeroes(minsLeft);
    secBox.textContent = addZeroes(secsLeft);
  }
}

let i = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
countdown();
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="countdown">
      <div class="box">
          <span class="num" id="year-box">00</span>
          <span class="text">Years</span>
        </div>  
      <div class="box">
        <span class="num" id="day-box">00</span>
        <span class="text">Days</span>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <span class="num" id="hr-box">00</span>
        <span class="text">Hours</span>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <span class="num" id="min-box">00</span>
        <span class="text">Minutes</span>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <span class="num" id="sec-box">00</span>
        <span class="text">Seconds</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Script -->
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Thank you

Comment: why are you calling countdown() function, when you already have called in setInterval?

Comment: It seems to work fine for me.

Comment: @Shiva Sai I changed the post according to your recommendations and added the original link where I got the template - as to your question, setInterval and countdown() were included because they were part of the template. As you can see, the day number is off by a lot.

Comment: ECMAScript months are zero indexed, so `new Date(2026, 07, 04, 00, 00)` creates a date for 4 August, not July. Also, the use of leading zeros for numbers is potentially confusing, just don't do it. Missing parameters to the constructor default to 0 (except for day which defaults to 1) so no need to use zero for hours and minutes.

Comment: @RobG Thank you very much for the help. It looks like my code should be `let endDate = new Date(2026, 6, 3, 0, 0);` instead of `let endDate = new Date(2026, 07, 04, 00, 00);`. It seems to give me a date that is consistent with the tool I'm using for comparison, whereas `2026, 6, 4, 0, 0` puts me one day over. I believe you said days default to 1, though, so that still doesn't make sense to me. can you clarify?

Comment: `new Date(2026, 6, 4)` will create a date for local midnight at the start of 4 July 2026 (i.e. 00:00 or 12 am). No idea why you're getting a day extra. Usually it's the result of creating a local date then getting UTC timestamp (e.g. `new Date(2026,6,4).toISOString()`) or *vice versa* (e.g. `new Date('2026-07-04T00:00:00Z').toString()`). But that depends on the host system settings (which determine the offset used for local).